# Dynamic Table row and button hover popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, yii

I want to achieve something like this,

[image]

When I hover on `./.` image in the table header, I want to show the popup with plus button, when I click that button it should add a new row with list boxes at the bottom of the table.

When I hover on the `./.` image on a row, it should show the popup with ok and delete button.

How to achieve this type of hover and can anyone suggest any way to do this?

Comment: Can you show us any code? You can use jQuery with .hover() .click() etc.

Comment: i want to create something like this i dont know how to create that vertical popup with buttons on hover,can you show any sample code or link?